# How to make Model to replace CustomMembershipDB

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I just followed an MVC tutorial on creating an image Gallery, which connects the Controller to the data connection, like this:

ImageController.cs:

```
...
private CustomMembershipDB db = new CustomMembershipDB();

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.lm_pics.ToList());
    }
...
```

Instead of connecting directly to CustomMembershipDB, I'd like to use my own Model named GalleryModel.cs.  I'm thinking this would allow me to create more functionality that just direct data access.

I am not sure how to write this model, or how to reference it in the controller so that it behaves the same way as a direct database connection does now.

Currently, my GalleryModel.cs file looks lke this (edited to correct error):

```
namespace LMProj_MVC.Models
{
    public class GalleryModel
    {
        public string Picname { get; set; }
        public string Decription{ get; set; }
        public int Userid { get; set; }
    }

    public class PicDBContext : CustomMembershipDB
    {
        public DbSet<GalleryModel> GalleryModel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to show the gallery using an iEnumberable list as I am doing now, in addition to creating other methods. Could someone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of your model object for each of your database pictures.  You could use LINQ to do this, for example:

```
var picSummaries = db.lm_pics.Select(pic => new GalleryModel{
    Picname = pic.Name,
    Description = pic.Description,
    Userid = pic.User.Id
});
```

Or you could use a for each loop:

```
var picSummaries = new List<GalleryModel>();

 foreach (var pic in db.lm_pics)
    {
        picSummaries.Add(new GalleryModel{
            Picname = pic.Name,
            Description = pic.Description,
            Userid = pic.User.Id
        });
    }
```

then return the view as before:

```
return View(picSummaries);
```

Comment: This looks promising but in the first one "pic => new GalleryModel" is underlined in red and says "Cannot convert lamda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type." Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: Do you have "using System.Linq;" ?

Comment: Yes, I saw other posters who had that issue, but it is at the top of all my files.

Comment: The lambda error went away went I removed the unnecessary GalleryModel method inside the class.  But now it seems that the result is not iEnumerable, so I'm trying to figure out how to make the data iEnumberable.

Comment: I used List instead returning View(picSummaries.toList()) from the first example.  Got it working.  Thanks!